# Default item on legend for QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend

when I make a legend in QGIS, everything shows up how it should except for one item.  The item is just a pale brown color that says "default".  I can't find this item in any of my layers and have no idea how to remove it or how it even got there.

Comment: Sounds like the 'all other values' category as it's called in ArcGIS. If that's the case it's a generic, catch-all value under one (or more) of your layers. You should be able to remove it in the legend properties under Legend Items.